# HowTo - Test JS Touch Events on a Mac

Tags: javascript, events, webkit, touch

I'm working to build a web app that uses the WebKit Touch Events JS API. How can I QA this app on my mac with touch events, and not be forced to swap between developing on a mac and testing on an iPhone. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the iPhone Simulator's built-in Safari app?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome Canary's developer tool should be working:

Open the Emulation panel in the DevTools.
Enable "Emulate touch screen" in the Sensors pane.
With the Device pane selected, select "Google Nexus S".
Click Emulate.

see official document here:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=zh-cn#emulate-touch-events